# phonegap app no network connection on Android 9 Pie

Tags: phonegap, android-9.0-pie

I have a phonegap app that is working on every Android Version except 9 Pie.

Navigating to a website works. That means my allow-navigation tags must be correct.
But sending a XMLHttpRequest I get no data.

```js
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
     if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
    if(xmlhttp.status==200){
      var info = xmlhttp.responseXML;
      if(info!=null){
       //doLog(xmlhttp.responseText);
        ...
      }
    } else {
     doLog("Server answer: " + xmlhttp.status + " " + xmlhttp.statusText);
    }
      }
    }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", serverURL + url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
```

I read you need minSdkVersion of 17 for apps to work with android 9. Mine has 19 already. TargetSdkVersion is 28.

Of course I use whitelist plugin.

```html
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-8.2.2" />
        <preference name="keepRunning" value="true" />
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
        <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="geo:*" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="mailto:*" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="http://*" />
    <access launch-external="yes" origin="https://*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Problem vanished.
What I changed before this release build:
Added

```html
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-8.2.2" />
```

Reinstalled whitelist plugin.